# Múltiplas conexões em porta serial

Tags: node.js, windows, impressora, electron, porta-serial

estou escrevendo um software, em Node.JS com Electron, que faz conexão com uma impressora térmica não fiscal, porém esbarrei no seguinte problema:

No cliente, eles utilizam um software terceiro que faz conexão direta com uma porta serial (COM6), onde está instalada a impressora, o meu problema é que, como ocorre a comunicação direta com essa porta, eu não consigo fazer meu software conectar com essa porta, pois ela já está ocupada.

Teria alguma solução pra isso? Algum software que faça a parte de controlador para essa porta? Ou alguma forma de abrir múltiplas conexões?